# has_many :through looking for inexistent column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have these 3 classes:

- `User`:

  ```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
  ```
- `UserStory`:

  ```
  class UserStory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :assigned, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :board

    has_many :comments
    has_many :watched_stories
    has_many :watchers, through: :watched_stories, source: :user
  ```

  end
- `WatchedStory`:

  ```
  class WatchedStory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :story, class_name: 'UserStory'
  end
  ```

when I try to list all watchers via `UserStory#watchers` I see this error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column watched_stories.user_story_id does not exist
```

It seems like the relation `has_many through` is wrong, but I can see the error. What am I missing here?

My migration:

```
class CreateWatchedStories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :watched_stories do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :story, index: true, references: :user_story

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Same thing: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column watched_stories.user_story_id does not exist`

Comment: Humm.. Because you didn't define it in the *migration*.. which is a common mistake we do ...

Comment: It is looking for a key named `user_story_id` in the watched_stories table but cant find it. What is the name of the foreign key you use to connect WatchedStory to UserStory?

Comment: @ArupRakshit so how should I suppose to do that?

Comment: @Sharagoz it is `story_id`

Comment: show your migration file content..

Comment: @ArupRakshit just edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `WatchedStory` and `UserStory` are connected through `story_id` you need to specify that, otherwise Rails will assume it's `user_story_id`:

```
class WatchedStory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :story, class_name: 'UserStory', foreign_key: :story_id
end

class UserStory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :watched_stories, foreign_key: :story_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column watched_stories.user_story_id does
>   not exist

Rails is looking for a column called **`user_story_id`** which didn't exist in your **`watched_stories`** table.

**Reason**

You have this line **`belongs_to :story, class_name: 'UserStory'`** in **`WatchedStory`** model,so with **`class_name`** specified as **`UserStory`**,Rails will look for **`user_story_id`** by default.

**Fix**

The error could be resolved by setting **`foreign_key`** option in your **`WatchedStory`** model

```
class WatchedStory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :story, class_name: 'UserStory',foreign_key: :story_id
end
```